# Function call results in type 13 mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, function, type-mismatch

So close to completing a large project but cant seem to get past this mismatch.  Any help would be appreciated. Hoping this is not too much info...

Getting an .xlsx single sheet file and need to add information to the data in a new book using a cross reference table to get business dates and periods.  Here is a sample of the source book:

[Sample data snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi3kD.png)

I got this code from @PGSystemTester as a vlookup solution to pull data off of a reference table using a date which would fall between dates in separate columns on the reference table.

```
Function rngLOOKUP(chkDate As Date, rngf As Range, theColumn As Long) As Variant
Dim acell As Range

For Each acell In rngf.Columns(1).Cells
    If acell.Value <= chkDate And acell.Offset(0, 1).Value >= chkDate Then
        rngLOOKUP = acell.Offset(0, theColumn - 1).Value
        Exit Function
    End If
Next acell

rngLOOKUP = "#Nothing"

End Function
```

I have searched and tried dozens of methods to format the date but cannot get past a type mismatch and am starting to wonder if it is actually the date that is the issue:

Here is a sample of the cross reference table:

[Cross reference table sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMTi7.png)

Each time I use this call to assign the result to a variable I get a run time error 13, type mismatch:

```
fYear = rngLOOKUP(aDate, rng, 3)
```

Here is the complete code.  The source file is .xlsx  and I format the cell the date comes from before assigning it to a variable.

```
Sub CleanDaily_Labour()
'
' CleanDaily_Labour Macro
' RMDC Payroll Resarch (MU) Report prep
'


    Dim myPath, fName, refFILE, job, JobGR, DateST, WKDay, PDWK, fYear As String
    Dim CRef, wkb As Workbook
    Dim shtDATE, shtJOB, sht As Worksheet
    Dim aDate, fYR As Date
    Dim rngLOOKUP As Variant
    Dim rng, rngJOBS, rngJBGRP As Range
    Dim SC, lastRow, PD, WK As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    myPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
'
' Get the file date and assign to variables
'
    Range("D3").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
    aDate = Range("D3").Value
    DateST = WorksheetFunction.Text(aDate, "YYYYMMDD")
    WKDay = WorksheetFunction.Text(aDate, "DDD")

    Selection.Copy
    Range("D7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
'
' Rename and save the active workbook by date
' set wkb to new workbook name and assign calendar cross ref
'
    fName = myPath & "\Daily_Labour" _
        & DateST & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fName, 51
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(fName)
    Set sht = wkb.Sheets("Sheet1")


    refFILE = myPath & "\Cross_Ref_fCalendar.xlsx"

'
' Remove extra header info
'
    Rows("1:5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
'
'   Insert Column to the left of Column D
'
    Columns("E:G").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
      CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
'
' Update Headers that will be kept / used
'
    Range("A1").Value = "FYear"
    Range("E1").Value = "PD_WK"
    Range("J1").Value = "JOB_GRP"
    Range("F1").Value = "WKDay"
    Range("G1").Value = "PD"
    Range("H1").Value = "WK"
'
    Rows("1:1").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
'
' Remove extra columns
'
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K:K,M:P,R:AY").EntireColumn.Delete
'
' Get the last row and fill known columns
'
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    Range("d2:d" & lastRow).Value = aDate
    'Range("d2:d" & lastRow).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy" (commented as no impact on error, tried variantions here to overcome mismatch but should not matter as variable never changed here, just the range)
    Range("f2:f" & lastRow).Value = WKDay
'
' Set variables for next steps
'
    Set CRef = Workbooks.Open(refFILE)
    Set shtJOB = CRef.Sheets("JobCross")
    Set shtDATE = CRef.Sheets("fcalendar")
    sht.Activate
    Set rngJOBS = Range("i2:i" & lastRow)
    Set rngJBGRP = shtJOB.Range("A1:b16")
    Set rng = shtDATE.Range("A2:f210")
'
' Loop through jobs in column i match job in shtJOB
' put matching group in row j (Use Function vLookupVBA)
'
    For Each jRow In rngJOBS
        jRow.Select
        job = ActiveCell.Value
        JobGR = VLookupVBA(job, rngJBGRP, Null)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = JobGR
    'end for
   Next jRow
'
'Save Progress during testing:
'
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fName, 51
'
' Fill in date parameters from Cross Ref file for Business date
' Use function rngLOOKUP to update variables then set ranges to the variables
' May be more efficient to get row number from cross ref table instead - later.
'
'    shtDATE.Activate (does not seem to affect)
'
    fYear = rngLOOKUP(aDate, rng, 3) '**This results in the error**
    PDWK = rngLOOKUP(aDate, rng, 6)
    PD = rngLOOKUP(aDate, rng, 4)
    WK = rngLOOKUP(aDate, rng, 5)
'
' Fill the columns with the variables (can likely bypass the variables and put on 1 line)- later
'
    Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value = fYear
    Range("E2:E" & lastRow).Value = PDWK
    Range("G2:G" & lastRow).Value = PD
    Range("H2:H" & lastRow).Value = WK
'
' Cleanup, save and close workbooks
'
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    CRef.Close False
    wkb.SaveAs fName, 51
'
' SQL call: Load to existing datbase (GDrive), use same format as Transactions
' ?? Get sales by day? vs maintain PDWK
'
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rngLOOKUP() expects a Date for its first parameter and a Range for its second parameter.  However, you're passing it a Variant in each case.  Hence, the type mismatch error. For example, in your code, you've declared aDate as follows...

```
Dim aDate, fYR As Date
```

This means that aDate is delcared as a Variant, not a Date, and fYR as a Date.  So you'll need to change your delcaration statement as follows...

```
Dim aDate as Date, fYR As Date
```

Same thing with rng.  And, it looks like the same thing for all your other declaration statements.

Comment: Thanks @Domeric.  Based on your comments, I changed the declarations to:

    Dim aDate As Date, fYR As Date
    Dim rngLOOKUP As Variant, fYear As Variant
    Dim rng As Range, rngJOBS As Range, rngJBGRP As Range
    Dim SC As Long, lastRow As Long, PD As Long, WK As Long

Note that rng has also been corrected.  As the function is set to return a variant, I also made sure that the variable that receives the result is also a variant.  Unfortunately still Error 13, Type mismatch.

Comment: Thanks @Domenic.  Updated all declarations but still the same result.  In this function call, does rng (declared as range and set to a specifc workbook.sheet.range) except the full path or should it be limited to "A1:B2" type of format?   fYear = rngLOOKUP(aDate, rng, 3)

Comment: Success!  Once I corrected the VB.Net declarations with all like variables on the same line to what you outlined as the proper VBA way - each variable must be declared separately, I still got the same results so with a bit more research, found that if the dates are all set to "m-d-yyyy", no errors resulted.  I had all dates in all files set to "yyyy-mmm-dd" originally and while all displayed as expected, VBA code resulted in a mismatch as my system time did not line up.  Also read (but did not verify) that US Std date is the way to go for any VBA code relating dates.  Thanks again.